# ImportError: no suitable image found when trying to import QtWidgets from PyQt5

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtwidgets

That's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chayma/pythonProject/venv/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so, 2): no suitable image found.   Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so: mach-o, but wro`enter code here`ng architecture
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

And that is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QWidget

class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("helloooo.ui", self)


#main
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainwindow = MainWindow()
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
widget.setFixedHeight(800)
widget.setFixedWidth(1200)
widget.show()
     

try:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
except:
    print("exit")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using a Mac and I'm guessing it's a M1 Mac.
I ran into a similar issue.

It is because PyQt5 does not have a `Universal2` build on PyPi.

You could try switching to PyQt6 which has a version for M1 Macs or you install PyQt5 via `Brew` [Brew PyQt5](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pyqt@5#default) which, according to the website, has a M1 build. But I did not test it.